# Setting a domain for sub domain

Tags: dns

Please is it possible to assign a domain to a sub domain?

I have a domain on a server (`example.com`) and a sub domain (`sub.example.com`), I want to add a new registered domain to the sub domain to be like `othersub.example`.

Comment: A domain can have any number of sub domains created. However what do you mean by having a full domain to become a sub-domain.. ?

Comment: What I want to do is to add a registered domain to an existing sub domain on a server.

Comment: You can setup a HTTP 301 on your new domain and point it out to the sub-domain. This is used to have better sounding domains names and redirecting internally to entities more reflecting hierarchy.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a CNAME DNS record.

A CNAME record points a domain to another domain.

For example, here is an example configuration in Cloudflare:
[image]

Where domain.com is the domain you want to visit in a web-browser, and domain.somewhere.com is the ACTUAL site that is being accessed in the background.

Comment: I want the main domain to remain the same but I want a to add a domain I newly registered to a sub domain, so it will be like a normal domain.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have used domain.com as an example, as a domain company owns it

Comment: @koslov, that's exactly what a CNAME record does. It allows a domain to point to another domain

Comment: On the domain I purchased I can't find CNAME record all I can find is Nameserver